# Prove that $\frac{d^n}{dx^n} (\sin^4 x + \cos^4 x) = 4^{n-1}\cos (4x + \frac{n\pi}{2})$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives

- **Question**

  Prove that $\frac{d^n}{dx^n} (\sin^4 x + \cos^4 x) = 4^{n-1}\cos (4x + \frac{n\pi}{2})$

---

- **My attempt**

  - First calculate $\frac{d}{dx} (\sin^4 x + \cos^4 x)$, that is, 
    $$\frac{d}{dx} (\sin^4 x + \cos^4 x) =4\sin^3 x \cos x - 4\cos^3 x \sin x $$
    $$= 4\sin x \cos x(\sin^2 x - \cos^2 x)$$
    $$\tag {n=1} = -2\sin 2x \cos 2x = - \sin 4x$$
  - Now, using the value of $n=1$, I calculate the derivatives for a few more values of $n$:

  $$\tag {n=2} -4\cos 4x$$
  $$\tag {n=3} 4^2\sin 4x$$
  $$\tag {n=4} 4^3\cos 4x$$
  $$\tag {n=2} -4^4\sin 4x$$

  - From this I observe the consistency of the $4^{n-1}$ factor.
  - Now I will expand $\cos (4x + \frac{n\pi}{2})$, which results in $$\cos 4x \cos \frac{n\pi}{2} - \sin 4x \sin \frac{n\pi}{2}$$
  - From what I know of of $\sin$ and $\cos$ functions, this fits the pattern I observe in calculating the derivatives of $\sin^4 x + \cos^4 x$

---

- **My concerns**

  I feel uncomfortable putting so much weight on *observing* a pattern, instead I feel I should be able to put it down in terms of *mathematics*.

  One more thing, I don't feel comfortable with

  > From what I know of of $\sin$ and $\cos$ functions, this fits the pattern I observe in calculating the derivatives of $\sin^4 x + \cos^4 x$.

  , there must be a better way to relate $$\frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}} (-\sin 4x) $$ with $$\cos (4x + \frac{n\pi}{2})$$

---

I would appreciate any hints, suggestions, and alternative approaches.

Keep in mind that this should be approached with the tools of elementary introductory derivatives and trigonometry.

Comment: Have you learned about proof by induction?

Comment: Use $$ \sin^4(x) + \cos^4(x) = \frac{3}{4} + \frac{1}{4} \cos(4 x)$$ and an easy $\frac{d^n}{d x^n} \cos(a x) = a^n \cos\left(a x + \frac{\pi n}{2} \right)$.

Comment: @Micah I've done very few proofs by induction. Would you be able to add it as an answer?

Comment: @Sasha I can derive $\sin^4 x + \cos^4 x = \frac{3}{4} + \frac{1}{4}\cos (4x)$ from $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1$, however I can't seem to come up with a proof of $\frac{d^n}{dx^n} \cos (ax) = a^n \cos (ax + \frac{n\pi}{2})$.

Comment: @Kermit the Hermit. Start with cos(x), and see what happens if you differentiate 1, 2, 3, 4... times with respect to x. You get the sequence -sin(x), -cos(x), sin(x), cos(x), sinx(x) etc. This is the same as adding pi/2 to the argument of the cosine at each step.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Note that if 
$$\cos (4x + \frac{n\pi}{2})=\cos 4x \cos \frac{n\pi}{2} - \sin 4x \sin \frac{n\pi}{2}$$

If $n$ is odd, then $n=4k-3$ or $n=4k-1$, $\forall k\in\mathbb{N}$, then $\cos\frac{n\pi}{2}=0$: $$\sin{\frac{(4k-3)\pi}{2}}=1$$ and
$$\sin{\frac{(4k-1)\pi}{2}}=-1$$

Now If $n$ is even, then $n=4k$ or $n=4k-2$, $\forall k\in\mathbb{N}$ then $\sin\frac{n\pi}{2}=0$:

$$\cos{\frac{(4k)\pi}{2}}=\cos{(2k\pi)}=1$$
and
$$\cos{\frac{(4k-2)\pi}{2}}=\cos{[(2k-1)\pi]}=-1$$